# Generate hash from two strings. Order not required

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash

I am trying to has two strings like `asdfg` and `zxcv`. I would like to get the same result when I hash them in the reverse order `zxcv`and `asdfg`. Can give me tips where to start? I am using nodejs and I know there are a lot of packages that can hash, but I'm not sure how to implement this way.

Comment: why not just sort the strings, and then hash them? use whatever hashing methd you want and just do something like `hash(['zxcv', 'asdfg'].sort().join(''))`

Comment: oh. i can certainly do that. Thanks! You can post that as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort the strings, and then hash them. Use whatever hashing methd you want and just do something like `hash(['zxcv', 'asdfg'].sort().join(''))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use MD5, which always generates the same result corresponding to the same input if you use the same salt.

Like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5